# Basic table association in NodeJS script using BookshelfJS/KnexJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm having some issues with my first BookshelfJS/KnexJS script thats has a table association. I copied the One-to-Many example pretty closely, just switched it from *Books and Pages* to *Driers and Cars*. However whenever I execute a query and include the withRelated item, it doesn't return the associated data (which would be the cars in this case), it just returns the drivers.

The association is One "driver" to Many "cars". I even used the KnexJS script in the demo to create the tables, so they would be nearly the same as the example tables. Heres the JS script for that:

```js
'use strict';

const Config        = require('./config');
const Knex = require( 'knex' )( require('./config').database );

Knex.schema
    .createTable('drivers', function(table) {
        table.increments('driver_id').primary();
        table.string('name');
        table.timestamps();
    })
    .createTable('cars', function(table) {
        // using Myisam, since Innodb was throwing an error
        table.engine('myisam');
        table.increments('car_id').primary();
        table.integer('driver_id').references('drivers.driver_id');
        table.string('make');
        table.string('model');
        table.integer('year');
        table.timestamps();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log('DONE',data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('ERROR',err);
    });
```

And just for more info, heres the table structure and the table contents:

```
mysql> explain drivers;
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | driver_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | name       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | created_at | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | updated_at | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> explain cars;
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | car_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | driver_id  | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | make       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | model      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | year       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | created_at | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | updated_at | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from drivers;
 +-----------+----------+---------------------+------------+
 | driver_id | name     | created_at          | updated_at |
 +-----------+----------+---------------------+------------+
 |         1 | John Doe | 2015-12-17 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 |         2 | The Stig | 2015-12-08 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 +-----------+----------+---------------------+------------+
 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from cars;
 +--------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+---------------------+------------+
 | car_id | driver_id | make      | model  | year | created_at          | updated_at |
 +--------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+---------------------+------------+
 |      1 |         1 | Chevrolet | Camaro | 2014 | 2015-12-18 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 |      2 |         1 | Acura     | RSX-S  | 2004 | 2015-12-11 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 |      3 |         2 | Ford      | Focus  | 2004 | 2015-12-18 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 |      4 |         2 | Nissan    | Maxima | 2001 | 2015-12-17 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 |      5 |         2 | Geo       | Metro  | 1998 | 2015-12-18 00:00:00 | NULL       |
 +--------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+---------------------+------------+
 5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then heres the actual NodeJS script with the models and query execution:

```js
// app.js
'use strict';

const Config        = require('./config');
const Bookshelf     = require('./bookshelf');

var Driver = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'drivers',
    cars: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Car);
    }
});

var Car = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'cars',
    driver: function() {
        return this.belongsTo( Driver );
    }
});

new Driver()
    .where({
        driver_id: 2
    })
    .fetch({
        withRelated: ['cars']
    })
    .then(function(driver) {
        console.log('RELATED CAR:', JSON.stringify(driver));

        console.log('DRIVER DATA', driver);
    });
```

Also, heres the bookshelf.js file, which contains the KnexJS and BookshelfJS connection:

```js
// bookshelf.js
'use strict';

var knex = require( 'knex' )( require('./config').database );
module.exports = require('bookshelf')( knex );
```

And heres the console output when executing the app.js

```
RELATED CAR: {"driver_id":2,"name":"The Stig","created_at":"2015-12-08T07:00:00.000Z","updated_at":null,"cars":[]}
 DRIVER DATA ModelBase {
  attributes:
   { driver_id: 2,
     name: 'The Stig',
     created_at: Tue Dec 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST),
     updated_at: null },
  _previousAttributes:
   { driver_id: 2,
     name: 'The Stig',
     created_at: Tue Dec 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST),
     updated_at: null },
  changed: {},
  relations:
   { cars:
      CollectionBase {
        model: [Object],
        length: 0,
        models: [],
        _byId: {},
        relatedData: [Object] } },
  cid: 'c1',
  _knex: null }
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, I have a feeling its something rather simple that I'm overlooking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues

1. The `cars.driver_id` needed to be *unsigned*, just like the ID column it's referencing in the drivers table
2. I was creating the table index columns as `${singular_table_name}_id`, which in my experience is the most common approach, but BookshelfJS expects it to be just `id`. So I could either change the ID column name to just `id`, or set the `idAttribute` value to `${singular_table_name}_id`

Everything works after the above changes.